# Trimming ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have an image which is 450px square below some text in a linear layout and wanted it to fill the width of the device, which I done by using;

```
ImageView android:id="@+id/my_image_container"
android:src="@drawable/my_image"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/orange"
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

This has worked in a fashion, but the ImageView element fills the rest of the screen and any elements placed under do not show.

Does anyone know of a way to trim the bottom of the space that the ImageView uses.

Hopefully this image can explain it better - I want to crop the empty area under the image (orange background).

[image: Example Image]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a `RelativeLayout` instead of a `LinearLayout`. You can then use `android:layout_above=""` and `android:layout_below=""` to ensure that you get the layout you want.

Comment: This is a good principle, but does not work for me. The image container extends way past the bottom of the actual image forcing the text below off the screen (see the image)

Comment: Hmm did you try using the RelativeLayout and setting android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" on the TextView?

Comment: I tried all sorts. It almost seems like the view keeps the size of the original image even though it gets scaled down. Any thoughts?